# Search and wildcard

Tags: search

Is there any simple way to provide searching with a wildcard using the Drupal core search engine?

I know it's possible with Apache Solr, but I'm looking for something very easy to implement.

I need to use it on i18n site.

Answer (score 1):

The closest module I have found for doing this is the [porter stemmer](https://drupal.org/project/porterstemmer) module.

> This module implements the Porter stemming algorithm to improve
>   English-language searching with the Drupal built-in Search module.

Comment: I've edited my question to i18n support.